# Batched vector and matrix products with unequal batch indices

Tags: matrix, julia

I want to compute batched matrix products and matrix-vector products for which the batch indices are different. With `A` as a (m x n x N_a) matrix and `B` as a (m x n x N_b) matrix

```
C[:,:,ia,ib] == A[:,:,ia] * B[:,:,ib]
```

and similarly a batched matrix-vector product, in which case `B` is seen as (n * N_b) vectors

```
D[:,ia, ib] == A[:,:,ia] * B[:,:,ib]
```

Both of these operations are possible with Tullio.jl:

```
using Tullio 
A = rand(10,20,5)
B = rand(10,20,3)
@tullio out[im, ia, ib] := A[im, il, ia] * B[im, il, ib]

C = rand(10,10,5)
D = rand(10,10,3)
@tullio out[im, il, ia, ib] := C[im, il, ia] * D[im, il, ib]
```

However, Tullio.jl is unfortunately outdated: It's not compatible with recent version of CUDA.jl that I require for other reasons. The solutions should work on GPUs and CPUs.

I tried to reproduce this behaviour with NNlibs.jl's `batched_mul` and `batched_vec`. The only way I could see making this work is to use `repeat` a lot to make the indices the same. This however causes a lot of unnecessary computations and allocations. Is there anyway to do this that is more efficient using NNlib or another library, maybe by directly using `batched_gemm`?

The other alternative I see would be to use KernelAbstractions, but ideally I'd like to avoid that, as I then also would have to define the gradients separately.

Edit: TensorOperations.jl also doesn't directly support the unequal batch indices, but maybe there's a way to write the problem so that it can be computed with it.

Comment: Sorry we should fix Tullio. But I think you can write a loop of batched matmul, like `for ib in axes(B,3);  @views batched_mul!(C[:,:,:,ib], A, B[:,:,ib]);  end`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yeah, updating Tullio would of course also be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted my question, the `Tullio` library was updated (thanks a lot!). So to answer the question: "How to compute batched matrix products and matrix-vector products for which the batch indices are different?", the easiest way to go is to just use this library:

The example from above now also works with CUDA.jl >= v4 :

```
using Tullio 
A = rand(10,20,5)
B = rand(10,20,3)
@tullio out[im, ia, ib] := A[im, il, ia] * B[im, il, ib]

C = rand(10,10,5)
D = rand(10,10,3)
@tullio out[im, il, ia, ib] := C[im, il, ia] * D[im, il, ib]
```